# Getting "App Not Installed" on some devices from signed apk

Tags: android

I have done listed points for fixing the same but no luck:

```
1.  Changed package name
2.  Clear cache & checked if there is no previous build installed on device
3.  allowBackUp set to false
4.  Version upgradation and target SDK changed (In this case app is able to install some devices but some other devices getting the app not installed)
5.  Selected both V1 and V2 checkboxes (Signature Version)
```

Is there any other thing to do apart from above points?

Comment: Go to device settings Apps and see if your app is listed there then delete it for all users and reinstall.

Comment: Must check that you have uninstall app for _Uninstall for All Users_. Also must be sure your password must be corrected while generation sign APK

Comment: @AbidKhan As I already said (2.  Clear cache & checked if there is no previous build installed on device). Also the problem is also showing for new device/user

Comment: @Piyush If password is wrong, I am not sure if apk can be generated. If somehow apk is generated then it should not be able to install on any device.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many solutions, I performed following steps which worked for me:

1. File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart
2. Added signingConfigs in AndroidManifest.xml

signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias ‘testAlias’
        keyPassword ‘testPassword’
        storeFile file('/Users/raj.sharma/test-project/keystore')
        storePassword 'testPassword'
    }
}

3. Now select “release” in Build Variants